# how to change form icon in windows forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer

please i need a help i'm writing a code for hangman game and i want just to change the icon of the form , i try that using the icon property but it doesn't work any more ,please how i can do this ,and also i do the following project-->properties--->icon and manifest but also it doesn't work this is my code for the game it work perfectly :

```
                  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                stage_count++;//strat from stage 1

               if (!int.TryParse(textBox1.Text.ToString(), out value))
                  return;//if user inter non_integer value do no thing and wait for new entry

               if (key ==value )//directly if user guesses the key he/she wins the game 
               {
                   //view the seventh picture in hangman game
                   button1.Enabled = false;
                   textBox1.Text = "";
                   textBox1.Enabled = false;
                   pictureBox7.Visible = true;
                   pictureBox1.Visible = false;
                   pictureBox2.Visible = false;
                   pictureBox3.Visible = false;
                   pictureBox4.Visible = false;
                   pictureBox5.Visible = false;
                   pictureBox6.Visible = false;

                   groupBox1.Visible = true;

                   label1.Text = "Great... You Got It ^_^ ";
               }




                   if (key > value)//guide the user to the correct answer
                        label1.Text = "Should Be Greater than" + value.ToString();

                   if (key < value)//guide the user to the correct answer
                        label1.Text = "Should Be Less than" + value.ToString();
                   if (key != value)
                   {
                       switch (stage_count)
                       {//this switch statement used to do some thing in each stage
                           case 1:
                               //view the first picture in hangman game
                               pictureBox1.Visible = true;
                               pictureBox2.Visible = false;
                               pictureBox3.Visible = false;
                               pictureBox4.Visible = false;
                               pictureBox5.Visible = false;
                               pictureBox6.Visible = false;
                               pictureBox7.Visible = false;
                               break;
                           case 2:
                               //view the second  picture in hangman game
                               pictureBox1.Visible = false;
                               pictureBox2.Visible = true;
                               pictureBox3.Visible = false;
                               pictureBox4.Visible = false;
                               pictureBox5.Visible = false;
                               pictureBox6.Visible = false;
                               pictureBox7.Visible = false;

                               break;
                           case 3:
                               //view the third picture in hangman game
                               pictureBox1.Visible = false;
                               pictureBox2.Visible = false;
                               pictureBox3.Visible = true;
                               pictureBox4.Visible = false;
                               pictureBox5.Visible = false;
                               pictureBox6.Visible = false;
                               pictureBox7.Visible = false;

                               break;
                           case 4:
                               //view the fourth picture in hangman game
                               pictureBox1.Visible = false;
                               pictureBox2.Visible = false;
                               pictureBox3.Visible = false;
                               pictureBox4.Visible = true;
                               pictureBox5.Visible = false;
                               pictureBox6.Visible = false;
                               pictureBox7.Visible = false;

                               break;
                           case 5:
                               //view the fifth  picture in hangman game
                               pictureBox1.Visible = false;
                               pictureBox2.Visible = false;
                               pictureBox3.Visible = false;
                               pictureBox4.Visible = false;
                               pictureBox5.Visible = true;
                               pictureBox6.Visible = false;
                               pictureBox7.Visible = false;

                               break;

                           default:
                               //view the sixth picture in hangman game
                               //it's the last try so diable the button and show the result
                               button1.Enabled = false;
                               textBox1.Text = "";
                               textBox1.Enabled = false;
                               groupBox1.Visible = true;
                               label1.Text = "YOU  LOSE ,, IT  WAS :    " + key.ToString();
                               pictureBox1.Visible = false;
                               pictureBox2.Visible = false;
                               pictureBox3.Visible = false;
                               pictureBox4.Visible = false;
                               pictureBox5.Visible = false;
                               pictureBox6.Visible = true;
                               pictureBox7.Visible = false;

                               break;



                       }//end switch
                       //to make empty focused textbox 
                       textBox1.Text = "";
                       textBox1.Focus();


                   }//end if   


            }

            private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {



            }

            private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {// if user want to playe new game the programm must enables the important controls and 
                //make the visible property equals to false for all the pictures boxes

                if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
                {
                    stage_count = 0;
                     key = (1 + obj.Next(99));
                    textBox1.Enabled = true;
                    textBox1.Text = "";
                    textBox1.Focus();
                    button1.Enabled = true;
                    label1.Text = "Guess a number btween 1-100";
                    pictureBox1.Visible = false;
                    pictureBox2.Visible = false;
                    pictureBox3.Visible = false;
                    pictureBox4.Visible = false;
                    pictureBox5.Visible = false;
                    pictureBox6.Visible = false;
                    pictureBox7.Visible = false;

                    groupBox1.Visible = false;
                    radioButton1.Checked = false;
                }
            }

            private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                // if user won't to play again just close it 
                if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
                {
                    radioButton2.Checked = false;
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean icon at the top left corner of form or in the taskbar?

Answer (score 1):

GO **Properties** window and change **"Icon"** property with your own icon.

Comment: i try this but it doesn't work it doesn't appears any picture to use

Comment: The pictures have to be 36X36

Comment: @System.Object: That's wrong. Any size as multiple of 16 in width and heigth will do it.

Comment: you need to add icon. That means ".ico" file.

Comment: You have to use "ico" as an extension of your image file

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform following steps

1. Add you icon to resouce file of project
2. than Asssing the created resource to you icon property .

> Icon = Resources.adobe_reader_icon;

Comment: i have added it but how i can assign it plese?

Comment: @bessanalbessani - check edit you can do it in constructor of your form

Answer (score 0):

You have to set it in the properties of your project.

If you start your application by pressing F5 in VisualStudio and the icon doesn't appear, take a look in the Debug-(Release) Directory. There should be the correct icon

Answer (score 0):

The icon of a form is only displayed if:
- ControlBox is true
- FormBorderStyle is not `None`
- Text is not empty

If so, you should then be able to set it with `this.Icon = ...`

Also the icon should be available as project resource. For this, you can just edit the forms `Icon` property, and in the following dialog import the icon from a `.ico` file.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<pre>
application root directory
application resources directory  **LIKE** ../../resources/dropbox.ico 
this.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("../../dropbox.ico");
</pre>
```

Answer (score -1):

1. First Solution then Properties of the project Add .ico file
2. Then open Form which you want icon
3. In Form property you can find Icon Field
4. There you can change Icon your windows form.